# update variable inside componentDidUpdate fails

Tags: react-native

I'm having a popup in my view and inside the popup there's a countdown timer. I need to hide the popup when countdown timer has value1 . This is what I tried.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.count === 1) {
            clearInterval(this.intervalDuration);
            this.setState({popupvisible:false})
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error when the count equals to 1 as follows.

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add condition in componentDidUpdate,

The componentDidUpdate is particularly useful when an operation needs to happen after the DOM is updated

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
            if (this.state.count === 1) {
                clearInterval(this.intervalDuration);
                this.setState({popupvisible:false})
            }
        }
    }
```

You can learn more about componentDidUpdate on official document :

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting a state variable, then that variable can also be added in condition to avoid recurring update.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.count === 1) {
        clearInterval(this.intervalDuration);
        if(this.state.popupvisible){
        this.setState({popupvisible:false})}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when `count` reaches the value `1` your`componentDidUpdate` sets the state and since there is no check to control when to update your state based on `popupVisible`'s value, your `componentDidUpdate` is called again and again causing an infinite loop. What you'd what to do is have a check if `popupVisible` is `true`, then only set it to false.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.count === 1) {
        clearInterval(this.intervalDuration);
        if(this.state.popupvisible) {
        this.setState({ popupvisible:false });
        }
    }
}
```